# Access - Query works fine when run manually but cannot create a recordset using it

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table titled Test_Table such as

```
   ID          Code
  -----       -------
   1             A
   2             B
   3             C
```

I have created a simple form titled **TestForm** to dynamically retrieve records from the table. The form element in question is a textbox and is named TextBox2

I created the following query and named it **TestQuery** to retrieve records from Test_Table using user-entered value in TextBox2 :

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE (((TestTable.Code)=Forms![TestForm]![TextBox2]));
```

The query works fine when I manually execute it.

I created the following sub-procedure to retrieve the query results in a recordset such as -

```
Sub Retrieve()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("TestQuery") 'Shows run-time error on this step
    MsgBox (rst!ID)
End Sub
```

But when I try to run this sub-procedure, I get an error stating '**Run Time Error 3061  - Too Few Parameters. Expect 1**'.

Am I missing something here?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access can evaluate `Forms![TestForm]![TextBox2]` and retrieve the value from that text box when you run the query from the query designer.

However, that does not happen when you open the query with `OpenRecordset()`.  In that situation, `Forms![TestForm]![TextBox2]` is treated just like any other parameter ... so you must supply its value separately ...

```vb
Sub Retrieve()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("TestQuery")
    qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Eval(qdf.Parameters(0).Name)
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    MsgBox rst!id
End Sub
```